# Spring-Security-Oauth2: Default login success url

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Is it possible to set a default login successurl for a Spring Oauth2 Sso service?

Following szenario

1. browser reqeuests `index.html`
2. sso service: Not protected ==> return the `index.html`
3. index.html contains `manifest` attribute ==> browser requests the manifest
4. sso service: Manifest is protected ==> returns 401
5. client redirects to `${sso.host}/login`
6. sso service redirects to auth server
7. authentication ==> redirects back to `${sso.host}/login` with the code in the query-String
8. sso service: requests token and redirects to the manifest file

Is there a way to NOT redirect to the last requested resource which was protected, but redirect to 'index.html' by default?

Please let me know even if there isn't a way to achieve this

Comment: Could you share some code, I don't have clear what you mean. may this help?: [setPreEstablishedRedirectUri](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/token/grant/redirect/AbstractRedirectResourceDetails.html#setPreEstablishedRedirectUri(java.lang.String))

Comment: Hi, Thank your for your time. It's hard to put this in a minimal code example. I will try tomorrow. Spring Security by default redirects after login to the last resource which was requested, but was secured. For Form-Login therefore i can specify an loginSuccess url but for oauth i cant find such a mechanism. I'will have a look at your hint tomorrow. The question is a bit old and i have to remind myself what i already found out

Comment: Sorry, but i'm currently not able to provide a minimal code example

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have (I think) a similar issue: in my case, once the SSO request succeeds the user is redirected to /, which is not what I want.

There is a built-in solution that took a bit of digging to find.

The `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` has a method `setAuthenticationSuccessHandler` that allows you to control this, so if you have access to the `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` you can set it to what you want.

If you have a setup similar to the tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_manual then you can simply add the following to the `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` that is created in the tutorial:

```
OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oauth2Filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/XXXProvider/login");
oauth2Filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        this.setDefaultTargetUrl("/my_preferred_location");
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
});
```

Comment: HttpServletRequest is wich libs?

Comment: I have same problem, how can i get access to existing OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter without creating new filter?

Comment: `oauth2Login().defaultSuccessUrl(...)`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to NOT redirect to the last requested resource which
> was protected, but redirect to 'index.html' by default?

Yes, in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
public class MyWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

[...]

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
[...]
            .oauth2Login()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("index.html", true)
[...]
```