# Spring Cloud OAuth2: Redirected AGAIN to login page after authentication as if unauthenticated when form login is used

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I'm currently studying Spring Cloud OAuth and was quite successful in doing SSO with HTTP basic in security server.

Now, I'm attempting to integrate form login (Spring default login page), disabling http basic. But whenever correct username and password are inputted, it redirected again to login page of the security server, as if it is not authenticated.

1. Client goes to SSO service (unauthorized)
2. Forwarded to security/oauth/authorize?... (unauthorized)
3. Forwarded to security/login, client inputs correct credentials (authenticated)
4. Forwarded to security/oauth/authorize?... (unauthorized)
5. Forwarded AGAIN to security/login

Here is my configuration for the security service.

```
spring:
    profiles: development
    application:
        name: security
security:
    user:
        password: none
    oauth2:
        client:
            client-id: client
            client-secret: 1234
            grant-type: password, authorization_code, refresh_token
            scope: read, write
            auto-approve-scopes: read, write
            authorized-grant-types: password, authorization_code, refresh_token
        resource:
            user-info-uri: http://${server.address}:${server.port}${server.context-path}/oauth/user
            token-info-uri: http://${server.address}:${server.port}${server.context-path}/check_token
            prefer-token-info: false
    basic:
        enabled: false
server:
    port: 8082
    context-path: /security
    address: localhost

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        builder.sources(Application.class);
        return builder;
    }

    /**
     * @param arguments the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, arguments);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    public static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin().permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout().permitAll();
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public static class AuthenticationServerConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin().permitAll()
                     .and()
                    .logout().permitAll();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my configuration for the client service:

```
spring:
    profiles: development
    application:
        name: sso
security:
    user:
        password: none
    oauth2:
        client:
            client-id: client
            client-secret: 1234
            access-token-uri: http://${server.address}:8082/security/oauth/token
            user-authorization-uri: http://${server.address}:8082/security/oauth/authorize
        resource:
            user-info-uri: http://${server.address}:8082/security/oauth/user
            token-info-uri: http://${server.address}:8082/security/check_token
            prefer-token-info: false
server:
    port: 8085
    context-path: /sso
    address: localhost

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        builder.sources(Application.class);
        return builder;
    }

    /**
     * @param arguments the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, arguments);
    }

}
```

Am I missing something or having wrong configurations? Please correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting the success login url. If you are using SSO with Outlook, GitHub, etc, this url must be specified in your application client configuration.

Comment: @Diego_Arguelles I have my own authorization server.

Comment: Ummm ok man, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39188986/4433104) i found an answer that i think gonna help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was with same problem and  the below code worked for me:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
    }

}
```

As stated by those responsible for Spring Security, as of version 2.0.4, Spring by default does not create a Session anymore, this causes the session loss during the redirect to the approval page. So this code: `.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)` will force Spring create a session for this approval flow.

I followed this sample project: [OAuth2ServerConfig](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/examples/sparklr/config/OAuth2ServerConfig.java#L69-L71)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality".  Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.